# React Native: Is there any way to get view hierarchy? (like get DOM tree in ReactJS)

Tags: react-native

currently I'm going to build a guided your component and trying to get view hierarchy in the app. Are there any way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use react developer tools (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools). Use:

```
npm install --save-dev react-devtools
```

then in your package.json in scripts add:

```
"devtools": "react-devtools"
```

and then in a terminal

```
npm run devtools
```

Hope it's what you need!

Comment: actually, I'm using in the JS code, maybe I need to dive into the react-devtools source code and find the way to get hierarchy.

Comment: @KevinVo did you get anywhere with this? Would be lovely for debugging hierarchy of transient states :)